# Updating cookie on change from number input

Tags: javascript, php

i have a shopping cart script that sends it's value across site through cookies.
So for example if i click on product page on add to cart, it will put 1 item in cart, but if i go to cart page, and update field with input type number, i dont know how to pass it to the cookie.
this is my input field:

```
<div class="product-quantity">
                 <input type="number" name="problematican" id="problematican" value="<?php echo number_format($values["stanje1"]); ?>" min="1" >
               </div>
```

And i can read cookie but it's value is constantly 1, only if i do 1 more time add to cart i can get another one. I need heads up on how it can be solved, so that even when i click on arrow up or down or even put number in field, it updates cookie automatically?

Cookies are set through php, and the one in charge of value is `shopping_cart['stanje1']`

setcookie data:

```
if(isset($_POST["add_to_cart"]))
{
    if(isset($_COOKIE["shopping_cart"]))
    {
        $cookie_data = stripslashes($_COOKIE['shopping_cart']);

        $cart_data = json_decode($cookie_data, true);
    }
    else
    {
        $cart_data = array();
    }

    $item_id_list = array_column($cart_data, 'item_id');

    if(in_array($_POST["hidden_fid"], $item_id_list))
    {
        foreach($cart_data as $keys => $values)
        {
            if($cart_data[$keys]["item_id"] == $_POST["hidden_fid"])
            {
                $cart_data[$keys]["stanje1"] = $cart_data[$keys]["stanje1"] + $_POST["quantity"];
            }
        }
    }
    else
    {
        $item_array = array(
            'tip_artikla'           =>  $_POST["tip_artikla"],
            'item_id'           =>  $_POST["hidden_id"],
            'item_fid'          =>  $_POST["hidden_fid"],
            'naziv_proizvoda'           =>  $_POST["hidden_name"],
            'cena'      =>  $_POST["hidden_price"],
            'slikas'        =>  $_POST["slikas"],
            'stanje1'       =>  $_POST["quantity"]
        );
        $cart_data[] = $item_array;
    }

    $item_data = json_encode($cart_data, JSON_UNESCAPED_UNICODE);
    setcookie('shopping_cart', $item_data, time() + (86400 * 30), '/' );
```

UPDATE:
here is a jsfiddle of what i came up with but for some reason i cant work it out:
https://jsfiddle.net/qju7c6dn/2/

Comment: Cookies are set on the server side so you need to send a POST request from your HTML page to your server. To do this you need to either use Javascript (listening to the change event of the input) or submit the form containing the input field.

Also, I don't know your use case but maybe you should use a session rather than a cookie.

Comment: @remborg cookie is already set for each user in this case. I agree i should do session or storage, but im working on complete cms written by someone else, so... Cookie is already created when user is on that page, i just need to change its value according to input field value on value change as provided in jsfiddle.

Comment: You might have to add `SameSite=None; Secure` at the end of your cookie string. But be careful with this, here is the doc https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/cookie